# Obtener cadena leida desde ZxingScannerPage, Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

me gustaría saber si saben como obtener el texto obtenido desde una lectura de código QR, en X.Forms, el problema es que no entiendo muy bien el código, el Device.BeginInovke... me confunde:

```
    private async void escanearQR()
    {
        // Página que escanea códigos
        var scannerPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        // Título de la página
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scannerPage);
        // Resultado del escaner
        scannerPage.OnScanResult += (resultado) =>
        {
            // Detener escaneo del dispositivo
            scannerPage.IsScanning = false;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                // return resultado.text ?????
            });
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tú código y en páginas como [esta](https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/) el ejemplo base esta montado para que tu, desde una pantalla, llames a una nueva pantalla de tipo escaner qr y al obtener el resultado es cuando lanza el `await Navigation.PopAsync();`

Yo en una aplicación tengo lo uso así:

```
    private async Task LaunchQRScan()
    {
        //controlo que tipos de qr quiero usar
        var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
        options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        };

        //lanzo la nueva página de zxing dandole un titulo
        ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        scanPage.Title = AppResources.qrTitle;

        //espero al resultado
        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            //con resultado cancelo el escaneo activo
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;
            //llamo a una nueva función que procese el resultado
            ProcesResult(result);
        };

        //lanzo esa página de escaneo qr "encima" de la página actual
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
    }


    private void ProcesResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            //quito la página de qr
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            if (result != null)
            {
                //si result.Text es un número, hago cosas con el
                int idMuestra = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(result.Text, out idMuestra))
                {
                    //cosas  
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hola, de partida gracias por tu respuesta, ayer pude dar con la solución, en realidad era por que no sabía manejar bien los conceptos de async y await y ahora ya entiendo como implementarlos  y cuando.Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, saludos.